# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\ln^2(n)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

I am working a maths problem and came across this sum. I am unable to evaluates it.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\ln^2(n)}{n}$$

I have checked on wolfram and wikipedia maths pages but can't seem to finds it.

**Can anyone please point to its closed form?** Thank you.

Comment: The Dirichlet eta function $\eta(s):=\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n-1}n^{-s}$, so your sum is $-\eta^{\prime\prime}(1)$. I'm not sure we can do better than that.

Comment: @J.G. There is an explicit expression for your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a CAS
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\log^2(n)}{n}=2 \gamma _1 \log (2)-\frac{1}{3}\log ^3(2)+\gamma  \log ^2(2)\approx 0.0653726$$ where $\gamma _1$ is a [Stieltjes constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants).

If we use, as J.G. commented,
$$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}n^{-s}=\left(2^{1-s}-1\right) \zeta (s)$$
$$\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\eta(s)=2^{-s} \left(2 \log ^2(2)   \zeta (s)-4 \log (2) \zeta '(s)-\left(2^s-2\right) \zeta ''(s)\right)$$ and then the result.

**Edit**

Let us consider the general case
$$S_p =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n\frac{ \log ^p(n)}{n}$$ The results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \frac{S_p}{\log(2)} \\
 1 & \gamma -\frac{\log (2)}{2} \\
 2 & \gamma  \log (2)-\frac{\log ^2(2)}{3}+2 \gamma _1 \\
 3 & \gamma  \log ^2(2)-\frac{\log ^3(2)}{4}+3\log (2) \gamma _1+3 \gamma _2 \\
 4 & \gamma  \log ^3(2)-\frac{\log ^4(2)}{5}+4 \log ^2(2) \gamma _1+6\log (2)
   \gamma _2+4 \gamma _3 \\
 5 & \gamma  \log ^4(2)-\frac{\log ^5(2)}{6}+5 \log ^3(2) \gamma _1+10 \log ^2(2)
   \gamma _2+10 \log (2) \gamma _3+5 \gamma _4 
\end{array}
\right)$$ where interesting patterns appear.

Comment: thank you so much @Claude Leibovice. I was about to lose hope.

Comment: @coffeee. You are very welcome ! I did not do much (a CAS made it). The good point is in J.G.'s comment.

Comment: i know, but you give me the result, that is all i want. now i can continue with my work. thank you again.

Comment: I am sorry to bother @Claude Leibovici, can you help me on the closed form of this sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{\ln^3(n)}{n}$. I don't have CAS software. Thank you.

Comment: @coffeee. No problem ! I just added a few more. Do not hesitate to ask. Glad to help.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.